# Resizing images in an EPUB (v3)

Tags: html, image, css, epub

I am building an EPUB for my in-laws that contains a collection of old scanned pictures, along with commentary.

Each "page" in the EPUB contains a header with the picture number, the picture and some text. The pictures are sized to 1024x768 in the EPUB, and I am trying to resize the images using CSS to display on the page. (I could just crunch the pictures down, but I would like to allow readers to tap on the picture and get a larger image if they want)

The HTML for this looks like this:

```
<div class="keepTogether">
    <h5>50001</h5>
    <div class="sized">
        <img alt="50001" src="images/50001-Front.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <p>
    #50001 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </p>
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
div.keepTogether {display:inline-block; page-break-before:always;}
h5 { text-align: center; font-style:italic; margin: 0px; }
div.sized { max-height: 40%; width: auto; }
img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
```

The problem is that this doesn't work.  The images show up on the page (in iBooks on the Mac and on the iPad) as almost full-screen, with only the header sharing the page with them. The text is mostly pushed off onto the next page.

I have loaded the HTML up in Chrome, and used the developer tools to make sure that all the connections are correct. If I muck with `div.sized { max-width: 40%; height: auto; }` in Chrome, the images resize appropriately.

Am I doing something basic wrong here?
Does iBooks just not support this kind of CSS resizing?
Is there an alternate way of accomplishing what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More info: If I change the CSS to `div.sized { max-height: 400px; width: auto; }`, then the pictures change size appropriately. For a single screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I have mixed experience with resizing images, depending on the reader and depending on scaling the image itself or embedding it into a scaled `div` element.

Over here at [Bookalope](https://bookalope.net/) we really limit the use of `div` elements, and use it only around an image to scale it. Try adding `width:100%` and `height:100%` to the `img` element. Furthermore, iBooks does have some quirks around image resizing: take a look at [this](http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2010/05/controlling-image-size-in-ibooks-on.html) post although it might be somewhat dated.

Are you trying to set up a caption with your image?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to keep an image and a caption together on a page.

Comment: That will be difficult, because some ereader apps/devices don't honor `div` elements completely and will break them across pages anyway. If you want to enforce captions, make them part of the image itself, else I'd follow the best-intent approach and accept that sometimes the caption slips.